# Width of many TD elements not equal width of table, but math should be exact

Tags: css, html-table

I have the following code:

```
<table id="theTable" class="theTable">
  <thead id="theHead" class="theHead">
    <tr>
      <!--42 td tags-->
```

The CSS is:

```
.theTable{
    position:relative;
    z-index: -10;
    width: 12012px;
    top: -19px;
}
.theTable td, .theTable th{
    border-style: none none solid;
    border-width: medium medium 1px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 286px;
    text-align: center;
}
.theHead{
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
```

So `<table>` width should be 12,012px and `<thead>` width should be 286 x 42 = 12,012.

Looking in Firebug, the width of the `<table>` is, indeed, 12,012.  However, the width of the `<thead>` is 12,008.  Why is there a difference here?

This is in FireFox 28.0 Windows 7, 64-bit

**UPDATE**

Thanks to a suggestion by @j08691, the `<table>` and `<thead>` are the same width, but the `<td>` tags are not the same width, throughout.  They seem to fluctuate between 283 and 289

Comment: Tried adding `border-collapse: collapse` to `.theTable`?

Comment: @j08691 You wizards and your magic.

Comment: That fix it? If so I'll drop that in as an answer.

Comment: @j08691 The `<thead>` is the correct width, but the `<td>` are still not playing nice.  The `<td>` seem to range between 263 and 269?

Comment: ^^^^^^ Forgot to add in the padding, 283 to 289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `padding: 10px;` will effectively add 20px in width to each `td`.